# How can i use datatables in meteor on windows?

Tags: mongodb, datatables, meteor

How can i use datatables in meteor on windows?

Comment: Please elaborate your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you mean is you want to use Tim Heckel's datatable's package for meteorite?

Meteorite is unsupported on windows, but that doesn't mean you can't use the packages!

1) Download or git clone his repo at : https://github.com/TimHeckel/meteor-datatables

2) Copy the files over from `/lib` into your project directory's `/client/lib` folder.

Then you can use it as normal

Comment: But i get this error: Exception from Deps afterFlush function: TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null. sorting, searcbing and paging works fine. CRUD. but is is not updating the DOM with newly inserted data.

Comment: @SarfrazAhmad This is because you're changing the tables after you've run `.dataTables` using reactive meteor stuff. They don't play well together this way you can serve non reactive stuff by using `reactive: false` as an option in your `.find({}, {reactive:false})` query. The new Meteor UI will fix this

Comment: I I do reactive false means it will not update the DOM with the recently created model. means max of meteor functionality will be ignored

Comment: okay tell me, i have added dataTable to a class, can i remove this dataTable plugin dynamially after adding it???? if yes then how? thanx